# Silverlight MediaElement, choosing local disc file

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, media-player

I'm trying to make a Media Player where you can choose either to render a file from url or local disc. I had no problem making it to open and render url file

```
void LoadVideo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadVideo.IsEnabled = false;
            mediaElement.Source = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
```

With `string path = "http://www.blablabla.com/movie.wmv"`

The problem occurs when I'm trying to specify local disc file path(as "c:\movie.wmv" or @"c:\movie.wmv"). It simply doesn't work that way.

As far as I have read, you don't have direct access to files on your hard drive besides those which already are in the project directory. What I want to do is:

- use Dialog Box to choose a file to open
- save the path of file into string and transfer it to MediaElement.Source

Unfortunately, I don't have a clue how to do it. I would be grateful for any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this should do the trick:

```
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog(); //you need to use the OpenFileDialog, otherwise Silverlight will throw a tantrum ;)
        fdlg.Filter = "MP4 Files|*.mp4|AVI files|*.avi"; //set a file selection filter

        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() != true) //ShowDialog returns a bool? to indicate if the user clicked OK after picking a file
            return;

        var stream = fdlg.File.OpenRead(); //get the file stream
        //Media is a MediaElement object in XAML
        Media.SetSource(stream); //bread and butter

        Media.Play(); //no idea what this does
```

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221415%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) an extensive example on how to use the `OpenFileDialog`. As for the `MediaElement`, you can see in the code above all you needed was the `SetSource()` method (as opposed to the `Source` property).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's so simple by using SetSource method. Cheers i pozdrawiam;)